# Pixel Shader stage did not run

Tags: shaders, directx, sharpdx

I can't figure out why the pixel shader won't run. I'm using the Blinn-Phong per-pixel shader from [here](https://takinginitiative.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/directx-10-tutorial-8-lighting-theory-and-hlsl/). Only change I've made is that I pass an aditional color per vertex which gets multiplied by the light-color in the pixel shader.

So far the Graphics Analyzer shows me a valid IA-result and the same (okay looking) result in the VS-stage. I disabled depth-stencil for testing and though everything looks rather fine I always see "*Stage did not run. No output.*" when I inspect the captured frame.

This is my **Projection**-matrix:

```
_projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float) Math.PI / 4.0f, viewports[0].Width / viewports[0].Height,
            0.1f, 100f);
```

Values are *Width*: 1346, *Height*: 800

My **View** is calculated like this:

```
_rotation = Quaternion.RotationYawPitchRoll(Yaw, Pitch, Roll);
Vector3.Transform(ref _target, ref _rotation, out _target);

Vector3 up = Vector3.UnitY;
Vector3.Transform(ref up, ref _rotation, out up);

_view = Matrix.LookAtLH(Position, _target, up);
```

Whereas *Position*: X:50, Y:50, Z:-300, *Target*: X:50, Y:50, Z:0 and *Yaw, Pitch, Roll* are all 0.

**World**-Matrix is currently *Matrix.Identity*.

The **quad** I try to render spans itself from X:0, Y:0 to X:100, Y:100 with *4 vertices* and *6 indices*.

I first thought that *SV_POSITION* must be a normalized value since it's obviously a SV-coordinate and someone posted in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007196/directx11-hlsl-shaders-not-running) that this solved his problem - but then the VS-stage does not show anything at all and PS still won't run.

It's been quite some years since I last worked with DirectX so I'm not sure anymore why this happens.

[image: Graphics Analyzer View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input w values are zeros.

The mathematical principles which projection matrices are based on rely on the 
input vector w element to be 1.0. The GPU later uses the resulting w element of each position vector to perform the **perspective divide**.

In your case, your projection cannot work (because you input w = 0) and the perspective divide is a divide-by-zero.

Comment: You're correct. I figured this out a while ago, but this was ultimately the issue. I was used to not having to set the w-coordinate manually as XNA did that automatically. Thus I overlooked it all the time.